# How to run Selenium TestNG scripts from command line on windows OS

Tags: selenium, testng

I followed the instructions given in this post. But I get the message "Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Running test from CMD is quite easy.

Follow below steps

1- Go to home directory and Set class path

Home Directory > set classpath=Home Directory\bin; and press enter

Home Directory > set classpath=Home Directory\lib*; and press enter

2-Home-directory > java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

http://learn-automation.com/execute-selenium-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the classpath you are setting in first statement (set classpath=Home Directory\bin) by second statement (set classpath= Home Directory\lib*)

What you can do is combine both separated with semicolon (;)
set classpath=HomeDirectory\lib*;HomeDirectory\bin;

You can check what classpath is getting saved finally by just using 'set'

Comment: Ishan, I did follow your recommendation. I get the following error.                                            C:\Java\Selenium\LearningSelenium>java org,testng.TestNG C:\Java\Selenium\LearningSelenium\xmlfiles\CETesting.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org,testng.TestNG

Comment: I think you should be including the place where your testng jar is present.

Comment: if that is not present in your HomeDirectory\lib. Say if your testng jar is present in HomeDirectory\Testng\testng.jar Try with -cp to mention the classpath. Try:  java -cp  "HomeDirectory\lib\*;HomeDirectory\bin;HomeDirectory\Testng\testng.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: Ishan,  the testng.jar exists in lib folder. but I still get the same error that it can't load main class org.testng.TestNG.   
C:\Java\Selenium\LearningSelenium\lib>java org.testng.TestNG C:\Java\Selenium\LearningSelenium\xmlfiles\CETesting.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Comment: http://qtp-automate.blogspot.com/2011/10/running-selenium-testng-test-from.html this link was very helpful